# Python - Comparing two lists and update a third one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi I am not a proficient user of Python, I stumble upon this problem. I have the following 3 lists **(ss1 cannot have negative numbers, g1 and w1 can take values >= 0)**:

```
g1 = [2,0,1,1]
w1 = [1,0,3,1]
ss1 = [33, 45, 66, 54]
```

In my toy example I would like to compare element wise first elements from lists **g1** and **w1** **e.g.** `g1[0] == w1[0]`, if this **true** we multiply `g1[0]*2` and add the sum from last operation into `ss1 (ss1[0] += g1[0]*2)`, `if the g1[0] != w1[0]` we would like would like to take the absolute difference between `g1[0]` and `w1[0]` with **minus sign** or `w1[0] = -abs(g1[0] - w1[0])` and the result from this operation to add into `ss1` or `ss1[0] += w1[0]`.

I came up with a naïve solution:

```
if  g1[0] == w1[0]:
    ss1[0] += g1[0]*2
else:
    w1[0] = -abs(g1[0] - w1[0])
    ss1[0] += w1[0]
print(ss1)
if  g1[1] == w1[1]:
    ss1[1] += g1[1]*2
else:
    w1[1] = -abs(g1[1] - w1[1])
    ss1[1] += w1[1]
print(ss1)
if  g1[2] == w1[2]:
    ss1[2] += g1[2]*2
else:
    w1[2] = -abs(g1[2] - w1[2])
    ss1[2] += w1[2]
print(ss1)
if  g1[3] == w1[3]:
    ss1[3] += g1[3]*2
else:
    w1[3] = -abs(g1[3] - w1[3])
    ss1[3] += w1[3]
print(ss1)
```

And the desired output is `[32, 45, 64, 56]`.

I was thinking of using enumator in order to solve this problem.

Would like to help how I do it in more efficient way and put this into function. How I can build a loop to iterate and compare each element wise and consider adding operation. You are welcome to suggest your solution.  If I have the same problem with **numerous lists** (*e.g. I have the same triplets’ g2, ww2, ss2*) what would be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `list comprehension`,

```
ss1 = [(z+(x*2)) if x == y else (z-abs(x - y)) for x,y,z in zip(g1,w1,ss1)]
```

**Result**

```
[32, 45, 64, 56]
```

Comment: You don't need to use zip two times. Just write `for x, y, z in zip(g1,w1,ss1)`.

Comment: @Rahul K P. Thanks for solution it is very elegant. Is it possible the result from list comprehension to take place into **ss1**. I mean to update values into **ss1** should reassign again?

Comment: @vasiop, You can just reassign the result to ss1.

Comment: @Rahul K P Thank you for help I really appreciated your solution. I cannot express my gratitude towards you :). Again super thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(list(map(lambda x: (x[2]+(x[0]*2)) if x[0] == x[1] else (x[2] -abs(x[0] - x[1])),zip(g1,w1,ss1))))
```

Output:

```
[32, 45, 64, 56]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a simple loop like this

```
In [16]: for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(g1,w1)):
    ...:     if a == b:
    ...:         ss1[i] += a*2
    ...:     else:
    ...:         ss1[i] += -abs(a-b)
    ...:         
    ...:         

In [17]: ss1
Out[17]: [32, 45, 64, 56]
```

Comment: If I have let say 5 same triplets as one the example I need to add addtional if staments in your solution. **E.g.** g2, w2, ss2, g3, w3, ss3. Am I correct?

Comment: You are confusing me! What do you mean by "5 same triplets as one"? And yes, if want something else than what you've asked for initially you probably need different code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that accomplishes what you have set up. It uses your if/else code and the same lists. It is also in a function for you and I show how to use it in the code:

```
#The function:

#Input array so function can return all lists
def compare(array):
    #Assign values to specific arrays again
    g1 = array[0]
    w1 = array[1]
    ss1 = array[2]

    #Use length of one array as all are the same length
    count = 0
    while count < len(g1):
        if  g1[count] == w1[count]:
            ss1[count] += g1[count]*2
        else:
            w1[count] = -abs(g1[count] - w1[count])
            ss1[count] += w1[count]

        #Count up till end of arrays
        count += 1

    #Return modified arrays
    array[0] = g1
    array[1] = w1
    array[2] = ss1
    return array
```

How to use it:

```
#Using the function:
g1 = [2,0,1,1]
w1 = [1,0,3,1]
ss1 = [33, 45, 66, 54]

#Put values in arary

array = [g1, w1, ss1]
print array
#Prints: [[2, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 3, 1], [33, 45, 66, 54]]

array = compare(array)
print array
#Prints: [[2, 0, 1, 1], [-1, 0, -2, 1], [32, 45, 64, 56]]

#Putting array back into single arrays
g1 = array[0]
w1 = array[1]
ss1 = array[2]

print ss1
#Prints your desired output :D [32, 45, 64, 56]
```

Comment: Thanks for help nice solution.